# Asp.net mvc html.raw doesnt resolve

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Id.ToString()))
```

always return 0 in the Index.cshtml file placed under "EditorTemplates" folder

Am i doing anything incorrect

I have the model defined at the top of the page as

```
@model [Namespace].ViewModel
```

Comment: Is the Id value 0? How are you creating your model? Does your `@model` type match the type you're passing to `View()`?

Comment: That's wrong on so many levels...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The value of the Id is 1. The issue is that only Html.Raw doesnt resolve. Html.EditorFor and HtmlLableFor does resolve. I need the value of the Id to be displayed in a label as opposed to in a textbox .@model [NameSpace].FoodViewModel
<div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Id.ToString()));
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
</div>

Answer (score 0):

If the id is numeric, there is no reason to use `Html.Raw` at all. There is no HTML code in the value that should aviod the normal HTML encoding.

Just use:

```
@Model.Id
```

The value will implicitly be converted to a string, so the `ToString` call is not needed either.

If it doesn't show the expected value, you know that it wasn't there in the first place.

Comment: I tried @Model.Id. It doesnt work either. The issue that i am facing is that the values doesnt display using Model.Id or Html.Raw(Model.Id). It displays if i use Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)